# How to implement abstract class with abstract method in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a perhaps trivial question, but I cannot understand how I can use the methods of an abstract class based only on calling it and choosing the correct override based on the type of value I have as Input.

For example, if I have something like this:

```
export abstract class Parent {
    constructor(
        public type: View
    ){}

    abstract getSource(): string | string[]
}

export class Child1 extends Parent {
    getSource(): string {
        return this.type.view1
    }
}

export class Child2 extends Parent {
    getSource(): string[] {
        return this.type.view2
    }
}
```

And I wanted to call the abstract class Parent, and, based on the type, figure out whether to use the function in the Child1 or Child2 class. I thought you could do it like this:

```
export class AngularComponent {
    public _VieweSource: string | string[];
    @Input() set data(type: View) { 
        // here i need to return Child1.getSource() or Child2.getSource()
        // not calling new Child1(type).getSource()
        // but something like this: Parent(type).getSource() --> Child1 if type.view1=string || Child2 if type.view2=string[]
    }
}
```

the `View` type are this:

```
{type: "simple", view1: "hello world"} || {type: "complex", view2:["hello", "world"]}
```

Sorry if the question is wrong, if there are any questions I can answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a separate class and put the switch case in that. I don't think with inheritance this can be achieved. How will a parent know about both child in case it has to return selectively one of the two. You either need a factory or a repository for that, not inheritance.

Comment: @NalinRanjan 
Thanks, if you have time, can you give me an example? Because in reality I already did it with a switch but I would like to generalize it better. I don't know, maybe mine is not the correct method to do it like this.

Comment: You can create factory class, and add two methods of types to it. Create instance of factory class then call one of method based on your type, then inside method of factory class return instance of related class, this way you have your type selection class works. @RootAtKali

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to choose which class to use, based on the values in `type`. You should not try to let inheritance figure out which class to choose, a simple if statement is build for that.

```
export class AngularComponent {
    public _VieweSource: string | string[];
    @Input() set data(type: View) { 
        let obj: Parent;
        if (type.view1 && typeof type.view1 === 'string'){
            obj = new Child1(type);
        } else if(type.view2 && type.view2 instanceof Array){
            obj = new Child2(type);
        }
        obj.getSource();
    }
}
```